# Where to put i18n files in utility jar which has no WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, internationalization

I am creating a horizontal module which acts as knowledge base for all the verticle products.  I build the jar of my codebase independently which is consumed by all these vertical products. Each vericle product can be deployed on application server and can act as a web application.

My utility jar has an API class. Whenever user creates object of this class, locale is accepted as parameter of constructor. I have few exception messages which needs to be localized since these exceptions are shown on GUI. Based on the locale I load the bundle to get the localized messages.

I am not able to understand where do I put my i18n files inside my jar since it has no WEB-INF and is just a utility jar. Also how these i18n files will be copied in the WAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a message bundle you can call:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale, loader);
```

As specified in javadoc:

*... getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file. It generates a path name from the candidate bundle name by replacing all "." characters with "/" and appending the string ".properties". It attempts to find a "resource" with this name using ClassLoader.getResource*

So the main thing is that your bundles are visible to the classloader.

You can create in your project a package, say *resource*, and put your bundles inside it. Suppose that your bundle name is *mycomponent.properties* the baseName should be: *resource.mycomponent*

The content of this package should seem something like a list of i18n files:

- mycomponent.properties (this is the defualt bundle when no locale is specified)
- mycomponent_en.properties
- mycomponent_it.properties
- ...

This package is distributed in your jar within you code. A web module that use your component has your jar in its WEB-INF\lib (or in a shared folder of the application server) and your i18n exception messages too.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. i18n properties files are equivalent to .class file and are located by the classloader. As long as loader sees it (in my case my jar in WEB-INF/lib folder) there won't be a problem.

Comment: You got it Narendra ;)